# Failed to import junit

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

[image: My Build Path]

[image: Error in Eclipse]

Is it a bug in Eclipse? I have tried to refresh the project, restart Eclipse and system. Confused.

Comment: In addition to the direct answer, I very strongly recommend using a modern project setup instead of the obsolete style you have here. You can just go to https://start.spring.io, select "Web", and have a project completely ready to go without worrying about containers or deployment. Just use File→Import→Existing Maven projects in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a bug in Eclipse?

Nope.  It is a bug in the project setup.  It looks like the project's maven dependency for junit is incorrect.

You are using the wrong Junit JAR file for the test code you are trying to compile.  The `junit.framework.TestCase` class is from Junit 3, but you are using the JAR file for Junit 4.7.  In Junit 4.x the package names changed to `org.junit`, and the `TestCase` class was dropped.

Solutions:

1. Find and use the JAR file for the last Junit 3.x release.  ([This](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/3.8.1) might be what you need ...)
2. Update your testcases to use a newer version of Junit.  (Preferably Junit 5.x)

(At the time of writing, the latest release of Junit 4.x is 4.13.)